# Bloomberg Server API

Tags: server, bloomberg

I have a basic question about the "Bloomberg Server API" that doesn't seem to be answered in their documentation, at least to the degree that I am confident about it.

I have programmed with the Bloomberg API and used their market data and reference data services, but I wish to develop an application that doesn't have to live on the Bloomberg terminal.  Does "Bloomberg Server API" allow you to do this?  It seems like, from the documentation, that the Server API refers to you additionally handling authentication protocols/schema, but I can't tell if it allows you to develop an application server away from the terminal.

Comment: You are not allowed to connect to the Server API if you are not logged in to Bloomberg (either terminal or BB Anywhere) on the machine running the application.

Comment: @assylias - it's actually possible to "connect" to Server Api while no users are logged in to the terminal. Details are in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, in fact, to develop server side applications that run on a server, and pull data from Bloomberg at any time, even while no user is logged in to the terminal, however, data can only be displayed to Bloomberg users. Your app must authenticate the user before displaying any data. Authentication requires user to be logged in to the terminal from that device at the time. Once authenticated, the user doesn't have to remain logged in, i.e. data can be displayed while user is not logged in. However, as soon as user logs in to the terminal from another PC, the app should stop displaying  any new data on the original PC.

Comment: Plz Sir I`m new to bloomberg confused about SAPI usage
First:after installing sapi on machine with bloomberg terminal and letting the sapi process up , I will write an application by python code that import blbapi and use the sapi should this application be on the same machine , or it can be on another machine and give it the ip and port of the sapi process and should the other machine have bloomberg terminal too?
second:what about the client side, any browser which open this application should the clients have bloomberg terminal too? Excuse my naive question,Thanx in advance @Mourad Barakat

Comment: What is the reason for installing SAPI on a machine with Bloomberg terminal? Typically, SAPI is installed on a Windows server or Linux box.

Server side application typically run on a separate box than SAPI (although you are free to run both on same box)